# Do I need stationary time series for Bayesian structural time series (BSTS)?

Tags: r, time-series, stationarity, bsts

I'm trying to model with BSTS, with exogenous variables.

It appears that my y-sequence is not stationary. Do I need to diff that to stationary? Or could BSTS handle that?

P.S. I'm using R package bsts

Thank you for your time!

All the best,

Kathy

Answer (score 9):

No, you don't need to make the time series stationary. 
BSTS should be able to handle that. Stationarity is a requirement specifically for AR and ARMA models.

BSTS is supposed to handle structural changes in the time series, which means that by definition it should be able to handle non-stationary data - since a structural change in the time series would imply changes to the mean and variance of the series.